# Graphics card not showing on Civilization VI

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Upon opening Civilization VI, it does not detect my graphics card, an Nvidia 820M, instead using my Intel graphics. (It also has a strange graphical glitch which renders much of the game as blue patches.) It did not find the card when I just had `nouveau` installed, nor did it find it when I installed `nvidia-340` or `nvidia-375`. (I already have Secure Boot disabled.) I have tried installing various such drivers, none of which have helped. I presume that the graphics card is not being used by the rest of the computer, but am not sure. How can I resolve this?

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` returns

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT 
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 
610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GeForce 820M
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
```

while `prime-select query` returns `unknown`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command and also `prime-select query`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have done so.

Comment: The Nvidia driver is not used. Most likely Secure Boot is enabled. How did you install drivers?

Comment: I installed `nvidia-375` using `apt-get`, as it didn't show on Additional Drivers. (I had the same errors using `nvidia-340`, which is on Additional Drivers.) I disabled Secure Boot when installing `nvidia-375`.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?